# Handle onChange for checkbox

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-bootstrap

I have state that is `false` by default. When the checkbox is checked I want the state to become `true`.

```
state = {
    status: false,
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.value
    });
}


 <Form.Check
    type="checkbox" 
    label="Consigne temporaire"
    value={this.state.status}
    onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

The state doesn't change when I click on the checkbox. It is always false.

Comment: Do you assign the "status" id to the checkbox in `Form.Check` component?

Comment: i tried it but it's still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Checkbox should simply toggle a `boolean` value in the `state`, which makes sense because this is a controlled input. Try something like this:

```
state = {
    status: false,
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
       return {
          ...prevState,
          status: !prevState.status
       }
    })
}


 <Form.Check
    type="checkbox" 
    label="Consigne temporaire"
    value={this.state.status}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
 />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Valid types for the checkbox are: string | string[] | number (according to TypeScript). This means you cannot set the value to a Boolean. If you do, it throws an error: "Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | number | string[] | undefined'."

Answer (score 9):

I think there is actually two issues.

1. You should use `event.target.checked`
2. You should check the *checked*
   property

Make sure you set the id to "status" on your checkbox.

```
state = {
    status: false,
}

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.id]: event.target.checked
    });
}


 <Form.Check
    type="checkbox" 
    label="Consigne temporaire"
    checked={this.state.status}
    onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `checked` prop instead of `value`:

```js
<Form.Check
    type="checkbox" 
    label="Consigne temporaire"
    checked={this.state.status}
    onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try like this:

```
state = {
 status: false,
}

handleChange = (event) => {
 this.setState({
  status: event.target.checked
 });
}


<Form.Check
 type="checkbox" 
 label="Consigne temporaire"
 value={this.state.status}
 onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change event.target.id to status
 state = {
        status: false,
    }

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      status: event.target.value
    });
}


 <Form.Check
    type="checkbox" 
    label="Consigne temporaire"
    value={this.state.status}
    onChange={this.handleChange} />
```